# I need to find the maximum value at the second column from multiple files and for each line

Tags: bash, awk, max

I'm new here and don't have much experience with `awk/bash` scripts.

I have N files like the two ones below:

**FILE 1**

```
$ (name) Panel S1  ERP in dB (Load 1)
$ (id) 1
$ (Color) 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
$ (X axis) Frequency(Hz)
$ (Y axis) Equivalent Radiated Power ERP in dB
    2.000000E+01,    1.199872E+02
    2.200000E+01,    1.191595E+02
    2.400000E+01,    1.184038E+02
    2.600000E+01,    1.177087E+02
    2.800000E+01,    1.370651E+02
    ...
```

**FILE 2**

```
$ (name) Panel S2  ERP in dB (Load 1)
$ (id) 2
$ (Color) 1.000000 0.360784 0.000000
$ (X axis) Frequency(Hz)
$ (Y axis) Equivalent Radiated Power ERP in dB
    2.000000E+01,    1.002274E+02
    2.200000E+01,    1.093995E+02
    2.400000E+01,    1.186437E+02
    2.600000E+01,    1.179484E+02
    2.800000E+01,    1.173047E+02
    ...
```

Now I want to create a new file based on those N Files as follows:

NEW FILE (MAX value for each frequency)

```
$ (name) Panel S2  ERP in dB (Load 1)
$ (id) 2
$ (Color) 1.000000 0.360784 0.000000
$ (X axis) Frequency(Hz)
$ (Y axis) Equivalent Radiated Power ERP in dB
    2.000000E+01,    max(first line second column value from FILE 1, FILE 2, ... FILE N)
    2.200000E+01,    max(first line second column value from FILE 1, FILE 2, ... FILE N)
    2.400000E+01,    max(second line second column value from FILE 1, FILE 2, ... FILE N)
    2.600000E+01,    max(third line second column value from FILE 1, FILE 2, ... FILE N)
    2.800000E+01,    max(forth line second column value from FILE 1, FILE 2, ... FILE N)
    ...
```

So that in the end, e.g., I get a new file like this one (here considering only the `FILE 1` and `FILE 2`):

```
$ (name) Panel S2  ERP in dB (Load 1)
$ (id) 2
$ (Color) 1.000000 0.360784 0.000000
$ (X axis) Frequency(Hz)
$ (Y axis) Equivalent Radiated Power ERP in dB
    2.000000E+01,    1.199872E+02
    2.200000E+01,    1.191595E+02
    2.400000E+01,    1.186437E+02
    2.600000E+01,    1.179484E+02
    2.800000E+01,    1.370651E+02
    ...
```

Thanks in advance for your answers and support!

Comment: In the first 5 lines of new file, lines of what file will be displayed?

Comment: If as I suppose, the firsts 5 lines are irrelevant, you could try this: `cat file1.txt file2.txt | sed 's/,    /\t/g' | datamash  -sfg 1 max 2 | cut -f1,2` just with the two column lines that you need to join, e.g. `file1.txt` will be just:  2.000000E+01,    1.199872E+02
    2.200000E+01,    1.191595E+02
    2.400000E+01,    1.184038E+02
    2.600000E+01,    1.177087E+02
    2.800000E+01,    1.370651E+02

Comment: Hello Gioconda, correct, the first 5 lines are irrelevant. I don't have "datamash" installed on my computer and can´t try your suggestion. I have just asked my IT-Team for installing it and will give you a feeedback later. Thank you for now!

Comment: Hi Gioconda, the datamash program hasn't installed on my computer yet. But I think I don't need it anymore. Based on your answer and the answer from "Remove duplicates and keep line which contains max value from one column - LINUX" I got the solution for my problem as follows:           cat file*.txt | sed 's/, /\t/g' > temp_file.txt; then                                          "sort temp_file.txt -g -k1,1 -g -k2,2r | sort -g -u -k1,1 >final_file.txt"   Thank you so much again for your help and time!

Comment: Hi EduP, you're welcome. If you found the answer, you should answer it here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint and for your help again, Gioconda!
So here my answer again:
cat file*.txt | sed 's/, /\t/g' > temp_file.txt; 
sort temp_file.txt -g -k1,1 -g -k2,2r | sort -g -u -k1,1 > final_file.txt
Best regards!